# How to display post like a forum on wordpress site

Tags: wordpress

When we take any action(Comment/Update) on any forum sites old post that post come on top . Have any way to use this function on WordPress site ? Something like, when anyone comment any post this post come on top or when we update any post that come on top .

Comment: please R & D before posting questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you like to forums and post commenting reply like VBulletin you can use  pluigns

https://wordpress.org/plugins/cm-answers/

for more check the tutorials

http://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/5-best-forum-plugins-for-wordpress/

Thanks